# Extract all possible ordered sub-sets

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, combinations, subset

I have a set of elements from which I want to extract `ordered` subsets. What I mean by `ordered` subsets is that I cannot switch elements inside the set. I gave three examples to show how I am trying to solve the problem.

- How can I extract these subsets recursively?
- Do you have any pseudo-code in mind?
- **{ . }** = subset

---

### Example 1

Let `S = {f1,f2,f3}` be a set composed of **3** elements. I want to extract all the possible ordered sub-sets as follows:

```
-{f1},{f2},{f3} // {f1} is a subset, {f2} is a subset etc.
-{f1,f2},{f3} // {f1,f2} form a subset and {f3} is also a subset
-{f1},{f2,f3} // {f1} is a subset and {f2,f3} form a subset
```

---

### Example 2

Let `S = {f1,f2,f3,f4}` be set a composed of **4** elements.

Possible ordered subsets:

```
-{f1},{f2},{f3},{f4}
-{f1,f2},{f3,f4}
-{f1},{f2,f3},{f4}
-{f1},{f2},{f3,f4}
-{f1,f2,f3}{f4}
-{f1},{f2,f3,f4}
-{f1,f2},{f3},{f4}
-{f1,f2,f3,f4}
```

---

### Example 3

Let `S = {f1,f2,f3,f4,f5}` be set a composed of **5** elements.

Possible ordered subsets:

```
-{f1},{f2},{f3},{f4},{f5}
-{f1,f2},{f3},{f4},{f5}
-{f1},{f2,f3},{f4},{f5}
-{f1},{f2},{f3,f4},{f5}
-{f1},{f2},{f3},{f4,f5}
-{f1,f2},{f3,f4},{f5}
-{f1},{f2,f3},{f4,f5}
-{f1,f2,f3},{f4,f5}
-{f1,f2,f3},{f4},{f5}
-{f1},{f2,f3,f4},{f5}
-{f1},{f2},{f3,f4,f5}
-{f1,f2},{f3,f4,f5}
-{f1,f2,f3,f4}{f5}
-{f1},{f2,f3,f4,f5}
- etc...
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What new subset can you do when you add a new element ?

Comment: You miss one subset for both 4 elements and 5 elements. (Hint: number of solutions is `2**(n-1)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an array contains the set, modify the array such that there is one space between every element. This space is reserved for partitioning. Take any naming convention. `0` implies no partition whereas `1` implies partition. Now traverse through the array to recursively add `1` or `0` in the partition. All possible combinations can be generated.

Taking *Example 1*:

```
S = {f1,f2,f3}
S'= {f1,0,f2,0,f3}
```

So the subsets will be:

```
{f1,0,f2,0,f3}, {f1,0,f2,1,f3}, {f1,1,f2,0,f3}, {f1,1,f2,1,f3}
```

which is same as:

```
{f1,f2,f3}, {{f1,f2},{f3}}, {{f1},{f2,f3}}, {{f1},{f2},{f3}}
```

If you don't want the original set to appear in the set of all subsets, just don't consider the state where every partition contains `0`.

Comment: Just to expand, regardless of how you do it, what your really looking for is all possible permutations of the partitions. The number of partitions in any given list > 0 is L-1. There are many algorithms to get all possible permutations, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Comment: @Rikayan I have a question. What do you mean exactly by `Now traverse through the array to recursively add 1 or 0 in the partition`

Comment: @Ryan Very interesting I get it. I am coding it right now. Your idea is pretty simple

Answer (score 1):

Let's say set S = {a,b,c,d} contain 4 elements. All the subsets can be generated by writing 2 ^ n - 1 in binary and subsequent subtraction.

a b c d

1 1 1 1 => (a b c d)

1 1 1 0 => (a b c)(d)

1 1 0 1 => (a b d)(c) //The logic is to club all the 1's together

1 1 0 0 => (a b) now 0 0 can be further broken down into (1 1) => (c d) , (1 0) => (c)(d)

1 0 1 1 => (a c d)(b)

1 0 1 0 => (a c) now 0 0 can be further broken down into (1 1) => (b d ), (1 0 ) => (b)(d)

1 0 0 1 => (a d) *same steps as above*

1 0 0 0 => (a) now left with 3 zeros we have b c d as 3 sets now we can start afresh with 1 1 1 and then go to 1 1 0 and so on.

In this way we are able to generate all the subsets.

Comment: Thank you for your proposition. But I cannot have (ac) or (ad) as u mentioned in line **8**

Comment: as u can see I cannot switch the elements places in the array.